# Can't Play shoutcast stream on ios

Tags: xcode

I have a radio project on ios that's supposed to play mp3 stream, shoutcast stream and eventually mms stream.I've been able to play mp3 stream using matt gallagher's Audistreamer class but it can't play those shoutcast links like this one (http://68.168.117.130:8000) even macos can't play them without using an extra software.So, is there any class that can play such type of links? or i have to create one by my self.

Gracias.

Comment: ifit's a webapp abd u have ios 6+ then i think ios removed the posibility to play streams on webapp since ios 5.1.1
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17454722/apple-removed-the-possibility-to-stream-shoutcast-icecast-on-ios-6