# Apple removed the possibility to stream shoutcast & icecast on ios 6 only in web-applications?

Tags: javascript, ios, html, web-applications

I just made webapp with the possibility to add my favorite radio stations.

i tried long time ago but it didn't worked... so i was actually surprised that my iPad 1 with IOS 5.1.1 accepts every type of stream or playlist.

i can playback '.pls','.m3u','.mp3' streams, shoutcast direct links ip:port, icecast direct streams ip:port/audodj ... and prolly more. in `<audio>` tag

so i played around for 2 days and found also a way to get "Now playing" on some stations using the shoutcast "7.html" trick.

i added the logos to my favorite stations, made everything handle with touches and not "clicks" (slow), and also found a way to ovverride the scroll problem on ios.

yeah i was really happy until:

i tried on iphone 5 with ios 6 and ipad mini with ios 6.

'pls' & 'm3u' don't work anymore.

np... i can fetch the pls extract the stream and feed my audio tag with a direct link.

most of them don't work. but some work..

ok so i selected the streams that work and put them again in a webapp.

now the fun thing is ... everything DOES NOT WORK on webapps.

streams work only in safari mobile browser.

as soon i made the app standalone nothing works.

So to resume:

**In webapps with IOS 5.1.1**

'pls','m3u',mp3 streams,icy streams & shoutcast streams **WORK**.

**In webapps with IOS 6+**

**NOTHING WORKS**

what happend?

Comment: Please define what “doesn't work” means in this context, and/or add some code to your post. It's very hard to understand what the problem is from the waterfall of text in your question.

Comment: in ios 6+ 70% of the pls,m3u direct links don't work on safari mobile and as soon you add the webapp to your homescreen nothing works.on ios 5.1.1 99% works   on normal safari or as webapp in homescreen.in ios 5.1.1 there is no difference between webapp or browser.

Comment: there is not much code to add as there are many ways they feed you with radio playlists or direct links... the point is they are all links to mp3 or mp4 streams and on old ios 5.1.1 they work but the same one don't work on ios 6+. anyway i use javascript to change the audio.src dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the mime type of the content, like type="audio/aac" ...
See more at http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp

Good luck!